# Qt Show Icons from Resource in a selectable list

Tags: c++, qt, listview, icons, resource-files

I have 200+ icons in my resources in my Qt app. 
I want to know how can I list and show icons to user so user can choose one as user avatar sort of. Files in my resource is PNG files, I need to resize them to 32x32 and show them to user so user can choose one. I don't know which component is useful for it and how to iterate through a resource prefix in Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QListWidget` to show the images like icons in a list. There are also some other possible ways like using `QTableView` or `QListView` which require different implementations. But for the case of `QListWidget` which is more simple you should set it's view mode to `IconMode`, set your desired icon size and add the icons from resource to the list widget one by one. Suppose that the icons are in the resource with prefix names `icon1`, `icon2`, ... . Then it can be like :

```
ui->listWidget->setViewMode(QListWidget::IconMode);

ui->listWidget->setIconSize(QSize(32,32));

for(int i = 1; i<=200;i++)
{
   ui->listWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QIcon(QString(":/res/icon%1").arg(i)),QString("icon%1").arg(i)));
}
```